# Foreach function in Makefile

Tags: linux, makefile

I was trying to demonstrate reault of foreach function in makefile using the following:

```
dirs := ../../Downloads ../../Documents ../special-var ../subdir-test

files := $(foreach dir,$(dirs),$(wildcard $(dir)/*))

all : ; @echo all-files: $(files)
```

while execution I have following error:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `echo all-files:
../../Downloads/install svnentos6.mp4 
../../Downloads/Abacus-Fees.xls 
../../Downloads/DiskOnRAM 
../../Downloads/Device Driver(FPGA) 
../../Downloads/GNU make and Makefiles.mp4 
../../Downloads/openwrt 
../../Downloads/Study Materials 
../../Downloads/Images 
../../Downloads/spread-src-4.4.0.tar.gz 

Makefile-foreach-func:7: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

If I remove first two arguments from dirs. Then it has no errors. Or if I am adding the argument to only one directory up (../) then also there is no error. But for two directory up (../../) it throws error.
Can somebody help me to resolve. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is from (the shell running) `echo`, not from `make`.  As ever, you need to quote strings which contain special characters like parentheses (and generally [pretty much everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable)).